# Triggered scroll event doesn't have e.pageX and e.pageY

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    log("event:" + e.pageY + " - " + e.type);
});
```

`e.pageY` is `undefined`,
`e.type` is `scroll`

I need to get mouse coordinates from `e`. But `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` are `undefined`.

Doesn't `scroll` support it?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll event is not a mouse event.

You can try a `mousewheel` event (`DOMMouseScroll` in mozilla):

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.pageX, e.originalEvent.pageY);
});
```

If you really need it in a `scroll` event listener you can do it like this:

```
var mouse;
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    // cache mouse position
    mouse = {
        x: e.originalEvent.pageX,
        y: e.originalEvent.pageY
    };
});

$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    // read from cache
    console.log(mouse);
});
```

Comment: Old post, I know, but have you tested the performance of this solution?

Comment: Something that also works on mobile with touch would be good.